# AngularJS Abstraction

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I noticed that while using angular, my HTML became full of inline-js looking code.

For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-click="move('nw')" id="nw" ng-bind-template="{{northwest}}"></td>
        <td ng-click="move('n')" id="n" ng-bind-template="{{north}}"></td>
        <td ng-click="move('ne')" id="ne" ng-bind-template="{{northeast}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-click="move('w')" id="w" ng-bind-template="{{west}}"></td>
        <td ng-click="move('center')" id="center" ng-bind-template="{{center}}"></td>
        <td ng-click="move('e')" id="e" ng-bind-template="{{east}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-click="move('sw')" id="sw" ng-bind-template="{{southwest}}"></td>
        <td ng-click="move('s')" id="s" ng-bind-template="{{south}}"></td>
        <td ng-click="move('se')" id="se" ng-bind-template="{{southeast}}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It's more or less been beaten into my head that anything JavaScript should be abstracted from the HTML. I know that Angular is a bit of a special case, and it uses a lot of attribute like methods, but is it possible to separate my HTML and Angular like I would a DOM method?

Like:

```
var north = document.getElementById("n");
north["ng-click"] = function() { move(this.id); }
```

Comment: HTML & CSS were born to represent _documents_, think wiki pages. Documents are well... documents. They contain relatively static information. JS was born to enhance those pages. Thus, pages were expected to function without JS. Unobtrusive JS backs that up - your JavaScript is there to 'enhance' the HTML but it should be fully usable without it. JavaScript is external to, and is separate from the document which is again... a document. Recently JS got fast, and people started understanding how to use it - now people are building web applications and the previous assumptions no longer hold.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, but you're destroying the point of a declarative binding syntax.

At the end of the day, every "garbage" you would find in HTML markup is easy to strip out. Now try to do the same in your code.

In order to implement a true abstraction, you would need to develop a neutral wrapper over Angular, Knockout and every binding (and other things) libraries. Something like a *HTML binding provider model*.

It would be interesting, why not, but are you going to waste your time because you don't prefer unobstructive model binding? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why inline event handlers are bad, is (putting aside desired unobtrusiveness of JavaScript, which isn't going to be the case with Angular apps anyway):

- they reference functions in global namespace.
- the combine structure and behaviour.

The first point isn't valid in Angular case - those handler are tied to particular scope, not global object.

Second point is more subtle. Coupling structure and behaviour is bad because it makes it hard to write unit tests for such an app. This is addressed by Angular team in ["AngularJS" book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028055.do):

> There’s a simple acid test we can use to figure out if our system
>   suffers from this coupling: can we create a unit test for our app
>   logic that doesn’t require the DOM to be present?
>
> In Angular, yes we
>   can write controllers containing our business logic without having
>   references to the DOM.The problem was never in the event handlers, but
>   rather in the way we needed to write JavaScript previously. Notice
>   that in all the controllers we’ve written so far, here and elsewhere
>   in this book, there are no references to the DOM or DOM events
>   anywhere. You can easily create these controllers without the DOM. All
>   of the work of locating elements and handling events happens within
>   Angular.
>
> This matters first when writing unit tests. If you need the
>   DOM, you have to create it in your test setup, adding to your test
>   complexity. There’s more maintenance because when your page changes,
>   you need to change the DOM for your tests. Finally, DOM access is
>   slow. Slow tests mean slow feedback and eventually slow releases.
>   Angular controller tests have none of these problems.

So, the point here is that inline handlers in Angular are different from native ones, so using them isn't a bad practice.